# How does differentiability affect the extremum of a function?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

I have this function
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases} (x+1)^3 & -2< x\le-1\\
x^{2/3}-1 &-1<x\le1\\
-(x-1)^2 &1<x<2
\end{cases}$$

I'm supposed to find the total number of maxima and minima of this function.
The derivative of this function is
$$f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
3(x+1)^2 &-2<x\le-1\\
\frac23x^{-1/3} &-1<x\le1\\
-2(x-1) &1<x<2
\end{cases}$$

Now, the derivative is not continuous at $x=-1$ and at $x=1$,  and is not defined at $x=0$.

However,
$$f'(x)>0 \quad\forall x \in (-2,-1)$$
$$f'(x)<0 \quad\forall x \in (-1,0)$$
$$f'(x)>0 \quad\forall x \in (0,1)$$
$$f'(x)<0 \quad\forall x \in (1,2)$$

Since the sign changes thrice, should $f(x)$ have three extrema in $(-2,2)$? What effect does $f(x)$ being not differentiable at some points in that interval have?

Comment: The candidates are places where the derivative is $0$ and where it does not exist.

Comment: What are candidates?

Comment: aka critical numbers

Comment: But how can it have an extremum where the derivative is not defined? Shouldn't the derivative be zero for the function to have an extremum?

Comment: Go back the definition of local minimum: " A value $f(c)$ such that  $f(x)\geq f(c)$ for all $x$ in a some neighborhood of $c.$ "      There are absolutely no requirement on the derivative in the definition

Comment: @Tejas: Candidates  are the places where we **might** have an extremum. But at some we may not have an extremum.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I still don't understand why the points where the derivative does not exist or is not continuous be the candidates.

Comment: @mattbiesecker, so, $-1$ is a point of maxima because $f(x)<f(-1)\forall x \in (-2,-1)$? And similarly for other points?

Comment: I did not say or not continuous, but did say does not exist. Take for example $f(x)=|x|$. It has a local and global min at $x=0$ but the function is not differentiable there.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Ok. Got it!

Comment: @Tejas.  To be precise,  $-1$ is a strict local maximizer because $f(x) < f(-1)$ for all $x\in (-2,-1) \cup (-1,0)$

Comment: @mattbiesecker, Got it!

Comment: @Tejas: Note that your function is not differentiable at $x=0$, but we have a local min there  (a cusp).

Comment: Your overall analysis is correct, a little incomplete. Our function is continuous on its domain. It is increasing to the left of $x=-1$, then decreasing. So there is a local max at $x=-1$. Similarly, there is a local min at $x=0$, and a local max at $x=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Right. I was under the impression that I had to play with the derivatives in order to find the extrema. Thanks for clearing it up. :)

Comment: You are welcome. It did involve finding the derivative and identifying where it is positive and where it is negative.  The displayed lines in your post giving the sign of the derivative are at the heart of the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability does not affect extrema of function at all. Consider it as a tool which helps in finding extrema in case function is differentiable. 
In this case function would have two local max at $x=-1$ and $x=1$ resp. and one local minima at $x=0$. Function being non differentiable at $x=0$ indicates the graph will have sharp corner at that point.